# How to find the every td input and its respective id, value by the name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

From the following code I have to find the following details

1. Find the first td
2. Find the f01 name id and its value e.g apex_date_01_00,null
3. Find the f30 name id and its value e.g id30_14,2
4. And this should be repeat for the all the tds which headers="ATTR_VALUE"

Code

```
<html>

<body>
    <table summary="Attribute Details">
        <tr>
            <td headers="ATTR_VALUE"> <input type="hidden" name="f24" value="" id="id24_14"><span style="white-space: nowrap;"> <input type="text" style="width:100px" id="apex_date_01_00" name="f01" maxlength="11" size="20" value="" autocomplete="off" class="hasDatepicker"> </span> <input type="hidden" name="f06" value="424349"> <input type="hidden" name="f07" value="296069"> <input type="hidden" name="f08" value="LV FEEDERWAY 01 DETAILS"> <input type="hidden" name="f09" value="REPLACED DATE - PHASE L1"> <input type="hidden" name="f10" value="D_ATTRIBUTE7"> <input type="hidden" name="f15" value="U"> <input type="hidden" name="f30" value="2" id="id30_14"> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td headers="ATTR_VALUE"> <input type="hidden" name="f24" value="" id="id24_17"><span style="white-space: nowrap;"> <input type="text" style="width: 100px;" id="apex_date_01_03" name="f01" maxlength="11" size="20" value="" autocomplete="off" class="hasDatepicker"></span> <input type="hidden" name="f06" value="424349"> <input type="hidden" name="f07" value="296069"> <input type="hidden" name="f08" value="LV FEEDERWAY 01 DETAILS"> <input type="hidden" name="f09" value="REPLACED DATE - PHASE L2"> <input type="hidden" name="f10" value="D_ATTRIBUTE8"> <input type="hidden" name="f15" value="U"> <input type="hidden" name="f30" value="2" id="id30_17"> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td headers="ATTR_VALUE"> <input type="hidden" name="f24" value="" id="id24_20"><span style="white-space: nowrap;"> <input type="text" style="width:100px" id="apex_date_01_06" name="f01" maxlength="11" size="20" value="" autocomplete="off" class="hasDatepicker"></span> <input type="hidden" name="f06" value="424349"> <input type="hidden" name="f07" value="296069"> <input type="hidden" name="f08" value="LV FEEDERWAY 01 DETAILS"> <input type="hidden" name="f09" value="REPLACED DATE - PHASE L3"> <input type="hidden" name="f10" value="D_ATTRIBUTE9"> <input type="hidden" name="f15" value="U"> <input type="hidden" name="f30" value="1" id="id30_20"> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop over each `td` with headers 'ATTR_VALUE'

```
$('td[headers="ATTR_VALUE"]').each(function(){

   //find input with name=f01
   var f01id = $(this).find('input[name="f01"]').attr('id');
   var f01value = $(this).find('input[name="f01"]').val();

   //find input with name=f30 
   var f30id = $(this).find('input[name="f30"]').attr('id');
   var f30value = $(this).find('input[name="f30"]').val();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$('td[headers="ATTR_VALUE"]').each(function(){
  $('input').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr('name')=="f01" || $(this).attr('name')=="f30"){
      alert($(this).attr('id')+','+$(this).val());
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Find first `td` element:

```
document.querySelector('td')
```

find All 'td' of table:

```
 var arr =  document.querySelectorAll('td')


$.each(arr,function(i,data){
var f01id = $(this).find('input[name="f01"]').attr('id');
   var f01value = $(this).find('input[name="f01"]').val();

   //find input with name=f30 
   var f30id = $(this).find('input[name="f30"]').attr('id');
   var f30value = $(this).find('input[name="f30"]').val();
     console.log(f01id)
     console.log(f01value)
      console.log(f30id)
        console.log(f30value)


})
```